# What's the precise mathematical theorem that's being cited when people write "if we let m go to infinity"?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

I see this sentence used a lot but many times I'm confused by it. I imagine there's a theorem that's being implicitly cited every time this sentence is used. Could somebody please tell me which one it is?

In the picture included here, I don't understand why circle implies star and the underlined sentence does not explain it to me.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Basically, what they are doing is taking the limit as $m \to +\infty$ of both sides of the equation. This is [rigorously defined](http://sites.millersville.edu/bikenaga/math-proof/limits-at-infinity/limits-at-infinity.html) and basically, what the proof above is trying to say is that $\lim_{m \to +\infty} x_i^{(m)}=x_i$: As you go further and further into the $x_i^{(m)}$ sequence, the values of the sequence get closer and closer to $x_i$.

Comment: @mingus does my answer answer your concerns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is taking the limit of both (or in this case all three) sides of the equation/inequality/whatever. Which rules are evoked after that depends on the situation. In this example, it's a theorem that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n+b_n=a+b$$ when the sum is finite and both sequences converge (1), that since $|\cdot|^p$ is a continuous function, we can pass the limit inside of it (2), then applying the same argument for line (1) gives line (3) and finally we compute the two limits (4).

\begin{align}
\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum |x_i^{(n)}-x_i^{(m)}|^p
&=\sum\lim_{m\to\infty}|x_i^{(n)}-x_i^{(m)}|^p\\
&=\sum|\lim_{m\to\infty}(x_i^{(n)}-x_i^{(m)})|^p\\
&=\sum|\lim_{m\to\infty}x_i^{(n)}-\lim_{m\to\infty}x_i^{(m)}|^p\\
&=\sum|x_i^{(n)}-x_i|^p
\end{align}

Comment: small nitpick: there's no equation in the OP's question on both sides of which one might take a limit. There's an inequality.

Comment: True. Changed the sentence